# Using RASA to build an email-bot - in general about email-bots dialog management

Tags: email, chatbot, rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa

I submit a general question about how to build bots running through a email channel.
Specifically, about how to find solutions using [RASA](https://rasa.com/).

**1. E-MAIL GATEWAY SERVER**

Sending and receiving mail automation appears a "not difficult" gateway task. Need a gateway server that receive mails via IMAP and call RASA REST API, answering back RASA Core answers, sending back to user a mail via SMTP.

**Question 1:**

> There is any already done email gateway to be used as a connector to
>   RASA (or any other conversational engine)?

---

**2. EMAILS-EXCHANGE DIALOG MANAGEMENT**

Emails messages are just an example of long input texts, containing many related "intents". Here the challenging topic.

Let's escape the usual chat paradigm where a bot and a person exchange small talks with a back and forward made by few words / often just a single sentence, possibly in short elapsed time (seconds/minutes). In this scenario I guess the chat topics are pretty "contextualized" in the chat sequences of near turns. Chatting could be see as a "*synchronous messaging*".

Instead, let's think to a different scenario where conversation happens just via email-exchanges.

> BTW, My vertical application concerns an academic research in
>   educational realms, about using a "tutorbot" to let students to ask
>   questions to a tutor bot about contents of a course or everything
>   related to the course, examinations, etc.
>
> In this scenario the user send an email to the bot, as the recipient
>   were a real human teacher (maybe the student is unaware if the mail
>   recipient is a real human tutor or a bot. TBD/partially irrelevant).

The point is that within an usual email communication between people, users "collect" in a single text (the letter) maybe more than a single topic (say "intent" in our parlance) that are maybe unrelated each other (simple), or maybe there is a dependence among them (hard!).

The need of this "collection" of questions/topics is because the email
is an asynchronous communication channel, so between people email
exchange, is normal to collect in a single message a bunch of topics.
BTW; I call the email a "*asynchronous messaging*".

**Question 2:**

> How to manage email exchanges, From the conversation experience
>   design, with RASA technology, and in general with an intent-based
>   dialog management system?

My first idea is to tokenize the input text in multiple sentences, blindly processing them though [RASA NLU](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/nlu/about/), as a sequence of intents. one by one.
The bot answer will be trivially produce the NLG text just concatenating answers of above mentioned intents.

Example of user incoming mail:

```
 Hi Mr. tutor, 

 I'm very interested in topic X mentioned in video Y.
 Can I have more study material? Maybe some papers about it?
 BTW, what's examination next session date? 

 Thanks & regards

 giorgio
```

The tutor bot answer could be a concatenation of intents-answers, without any memory/correlation among answers. That's maybe can work for simple cases. See this answer:

```
 Hi Giorgio,

 I'm glad you are interested in topic X. 
 You were right to watch video about Y. 
 That's coherent with your study programme! 
 I also suggest to read these papers: Z, W. 

 The next examination date is to be decided yet. 
 I'll inform you asap via email! 

 Regards

 The teacher
```

In terms of RASA intents the input mail could be:

```
intent greet
intent interest_on
intent interest_more_info
intent next_exam
intent_thanks
intent_signature
```

In terms of RASA answers the output mail could be:

```
answer_greet
answer_interest_on
answer_interest_more_info
answer_next_exam
answer_signature
```

So far it seems simple... but what if input sentences are much or less related each other?

[Rasa Core stories](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/core/stories/), as a prediction of sequences of intents, of the input mail, seems in theory a winner solution, but is not fully clear to me how to implement the use of stories in application code.

Can you help me understand in practice how to possibly use RASA stories in this email context?
I mean: How could use RASA core to predict the next intent/answer, given previous intents detection?
Can you give me a code example? (I'm not a RASA/python nerd)

Thanks
giorgio

Answer (score 0):

I rethinking about my question and that's my first fit solution to be verified with community here. So I maybe simply need to "buffer" the incoming mail sentences splittingthese and collecting/"buffering" too the replies from the bot, to be sent finally as a unique email reply.
Here the nodejs rough code:

```js
  const listOfUndesiredIntents = ['chitchat', 'out_of_scope', 'interjection']

  /**
   * email reply 
   * @param {String} sender - email address or user id/name
   * @param {String} inputMailText - contains the body text of incoming mail
   * @param {String[]} listOfUndesiredIntents
   * @return {String}
   */
  const emailResponse = (sender, inputMailText, listOfUndesiredIntents) => {

    // full text is split into a sequence (array) of sentences.
   const sentences = sentenceTokeniker(inputMailText)

    const outputMailText = ''

    for (const sentence of sentences) {
      outputMailText += getFiteredRasaCoreResponse(sender, sentence, listOfUndesiredIntents)

    return outputMailText
  }


const getFiteredRasaCoreResponse = (sender, sentence, listOfUndesiredIntents) => {

  const sentenceSeparator = '\n\n'

    const reply = await getRASACoreResponse(sender, sentence)

    // output mail would contain just "meaningful" contents.
    // it would be better if it doesn't contain answers to some kind of intents, 
    // e.g. answer must removed if related intent is 
    // a fallback, a "not understand", an interjection or (maybe/TBD) any chitchat, etc.

    const intent = await getRASALastSelectedIntent(sender)


    return listOfUndesiredIntents.includes(intent) ? '' : reply + sentenceSeparator 

}


const getRasaCoreResponse = (sender, sentence) => {

    // submit sentence to RASA engine, calling HTTP POST RASA Core server,
    // to endpoint: http://rasaRunServer:port/webhooks/rest/webhook

}


const getRASALastSelectedIntent = (sender) => {

    // using RASA API endpoint: conversations/sender/tracker
    // returns intent name corresponding of last message processed
    // for details, see: https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa/issues/5768#issuecomment-623922786

}
```

> Note: `getFiteredRasaCoreResponse()` if for prune out "useless" responses (UtteranceActions).

Answer (score -1):

Boilerplate implementation that you have done in nodejs, only split email text and send sentences to Rasa API Rest.

For  email bots service the issue is that a multi intent scenarios should be defined.
Rasa NLU supports handle multi intent scenarios.

https://blog.rasa.com/how-to-handle-multiple-intents-per-input-using-rasa-nlu-tensorflow-pipeline/

Comment: Thx Ezio, my pseudocode split/sequentialize and (that's maybe the tricky part) also discard responses related to a list of uninteresting/unwanted intents (fallbacks/chitchat/interjection/etc.), to produce a final "coherent" mail answer. The multinintents pipeline requires to foresee in tarining data all possible combinations of multintents, that's hard in case of complex input texts. Maybe multi-intents are a plus, to manage few standard intents combinations (affirmation+blabla/negation+blabla)...

Comment: Another boilerplate implementation is FormActions.